# C# table/2D array type

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there any way to use any of .net's table types (usually used to represent either a database table or a grid control) as a generic table (a.k.a. 2D array) type? Which one would this be?

Comment: What are you going to be doing with this table? And why is a 2D array not suitable?

Comment: @Oded A 2D array does not have ability for adding/removing rows/columns. I will not be doing anything with it other then refering to it. No passing it around or anything.

Comment: We have a start on requirements... dynamic adding and removing of rows and columns. What else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that, even if it's possible. If you state your requirements clearly, we might be able to recommend you an appropriate data structure.

Comment: @CodeInChaos The requirements are simple: an in-memory 2D store of ints or chars with the ability to add/remove columns/rows (at least at the end, better if in the middle, too)

Comment: Is it sparse or dense? Is a runtime of `O(width*height)` acceptable for insertions/deletions in the middle/beginning?

Comment: @CodeInChaos Very dense (in fact, full)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)... adding/removing Rows/Columns supported.